# Hello im trying to use v-if but want to know what to type to have click of the button as true statement

Tags: vue.js

```
 <div v-if="boughtTicket">
     <ion-row>
         <ion-col size="3">
             <p>ZÓNY</p>
             <p>2</p>
          </ion-col>

          <ion-col size="3">
              <p>MINÚT</p>
              <p>30</p>
          </ion-col>

          <ion-col size="6">
              <div class="flex justify-content-between">
                  <div class="ml-3">          
                      <p>ZĽAVNENÝ</p>
                      <p>0,41€</p>
                  </div>
            
                  <ion-icon @click="BuyTicket" :icon="cartOutline"></ion-icon>
              </div>

          </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
 </div>
```

this is in ionic code and Im trying to make a function that if the button is clicked this whole code is going to be changed to different kind

```
 methods: {
    buyTicket() {
      if(this.buyTicket = )
    }

  }
```

this is my method. How can I finish the code please

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to say you want the `buyTicket()` function to do one thing the first time it's clicked and then change its behavior for the next time?

Comment: Hello Daniel, no im trying to make function buyTicket to change v-if boughtTicket to true as soon as I press the ion-icon. Than as the statement changes to true there will be different visible change to the element in app. Lets say the style is going to change

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "change v-if boughtTicket to true". If boughtTicket is a component state variable, and you want that buyTicket() function to set it to true, you can just set `boughtTIcket=true` in the function -- I'm not sure what you're trying to use `v-if` for?

Comment: Yea thats understandable but I dont know what to type into the function to let it know that it is pressed 
`buyTicket() {
if(this.buyTicket = ?) {
boughtTicket = true
}
}
`

Comment: The fact that the function is being called indicates that it was pressed -- the user clicking the button triggers the function. Sorry, I know we're miscommunicating here, trying to help but I'm just not sure what part isn't clear.... hoping this helps?